# How to use pytest to assert NO Warning is raised

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, warnings, pytest

I want to ensure that *no warning at all* is raised in one assertion.

Could not find any explicit answer in [pytest documentation about warnings](https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.2.1/warnings.html#assertwarnings). (dead link, the 3.2.* doc is not available anymore).

I've tried this, thinking maybe `None` would mean "nothing":

```
def test_AttrStr_parse_warnings():
    """Check _AttrStr.parse() raises proper warnings in proper cases."""
    with pytest.warns(None):
        _AttrStr('').parse()
```

but this assertion is also always correct, for instance, the test does not fail, even if a warning is actually raised:

```
def test_AttrStr_parse_warnings():
    """Check _AttrStr.parse() raises proper warnings in proper cases."""
    with pytest.warns(None):
        _AttrStr('').parse()
        warnings.warn('any message')
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**For pytest >= 7.0**

[The doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.0.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html#additional-use-cases-of-warnings-in-tests) now explicitely mentions this case should be solved this way (without pytest):

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("error")
    ...
```

though this may not completely solve some cases (dynamic checks: see [this post](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/9404#issue-1076710891)).

The solution suggested for pytest < 7.0, below, now raises a DeprecationWarning. Thanks to @Warren-Weckesser for signaling this in comment!

**Possible solution for pytest < 7.0**

Yet it was not planned to be used like this, it's possible to "record" any possible warning raised, and use this to add another assertion to ensure the number of raised warnings is `0`:

```
def test_AttrStr_parse_warnings():
    """Check parse() raises proper warnings in proper cases."""
    with pytest.warns(None) as record:
        _AttrStr('').parse()
    assert len(record) == 0
```

To ensure it works: adding `warnings.warn('any message')` in the second assertion let the test fail.

Comment: or even prettier: `assert not record.list`.

Comment: or even shorter: `assert not record` (see [usage example](https://docs.pytest.org/en/5.2.2/warnings.html#custom-failure-messages))

Comment: This does not allow you to filter records. For example `pytest.warns(FutureWarning): pass` fails since no `FutureWarning` was thrown.

Comment: FYI: `pytest.warns(None)` is deprecated in pytest 7.0.0.

Comment: Does the new solution only work on pytest >= 7.0?

Comment: @sourcream sorry for the delay; I don't know exactly. I think yes (because I renamed the second paragraph "possible solution for pytest <7.0" and not "mandatory solution..."), but to test it again would require to check against a new install with an older version of pytest, I just can't do that right now. If you have it already installed, you should be able to check it very easily.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation mentions two options: fixture `recwarn` or using context manager `warnings.catch_warnings`.

**Use `recwarn` fixture:**

```
import warnings

def test_no_warnings(recwarn):
    assert len(recwarn) == 0
    warnings.warn("Watch out!")
    assert len(recwarn) == 0 # Fails
```

**Use warnings `warnings.catch_warnings`:**

```
import warnings

def test_no_warnings():
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("error")

        warnings.warn("Watch Out!") # Fails
```

##### Which to use?

The second approach (`warnings.catch_warnings`) has better error message while the first option (`recwarn`) can be more tailored as you can actually manipulate the warning message/category.

For example, a test could fail for specific warning classes:

```
import warnings

def test_no_future_warnings(recwarn):
    warnings.warn("Watch out!", UserWarning)
    warnings.warn("Watch out in the future!", FutureWarning)

    relevant_warnings = [wrn for wrn in recwarn if wrn.category in (FutureWarning,)]
    assert relevant_warnings == [] # Fails
```

##### Links to documentation

- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html#recwarn
- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-warnings.html#additional-use-cases-of-warnings-in-tests

Answer (score 1):

If you have tests that are testing other functionality, but you also want to assert that no warnings were raised you could use a decorator. Here's one that I wrote based on the previous accepted answer from [zezollo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3926735/zezollo)

```py
def no_warnings(func):

    def wrapper_no_warnings(*args, **kwargs):

        with pytest.warns(None) as warnings:
            func(*args, **kwargs)

        if len(warnings) > 0:
            raise AssertionError(
                "Warnings were raised: " + ", ".join([str(w) for w in warnings])
            )

    return wrapper_no_warnings
```

You can then decorate test class functions to add this assertion.

```py
class MyTestClass(TestCase)

  @no_warnings
  def test_something(self):

      # My important test
      self.assertTrue(True)
```